# Unable to run function shared a prop to dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am passing my api call function as a prop from my form.js file into the dropdown component in order to dynamically retrieve the data from the database and populate my dropdown option as shown in the code below

```
<th><Dropdown label="Select Item Type" data={this.state.itemList} api={itemsName} valueCallBack={this.handleItemType}/></th>
```

"itemsName" is the function imported from my api file.
Code of the API is below:

```
export var itemsName = async() => {
  var response = await axios.get("http://localhost:9000/itemsName");
  const data = response.data;
  return data.items;
}
```

Here is the code for the dropdown component

```
import react from 'react';
export default class Dropdown extends react.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }

    };

    shareValue(e){
        this.props.valueCallBack(e.target.value);
    };
    
    componentDidMount(){
        let response = this.props.api()
        this.setState({data: response})
    }

    render(){
            if(this.state.data === null){
                return <div>Loading...</div>
            }
            else{
            return  <>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <select className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onChange={(e) => this.shareValue(e)}>
                                {
                                    this.state.data.map((item, index) =>
                                    <option key={index}>{item}</option>
                                )}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </>
            }
    }
}
```

But react keeps throwing the error "*TypeError: this.props.api is not a function*"

Can someone help me understand my mistake? I am very new to this

Comment: I don't see the cause for that exact error, but this definitely won't work anyway.  `itemsName` is an `async` function, so even without this error all you'd be setting as the `data` state value is a `Promise` object.  You'd want to update state with the *result* of the `Promise`, not the `Promise` itself.

Comment: @David Can you suggest me a better way to get this done?

Comment: Set the state to the result of the `Promise`.  For example:  `this.props.api().then(response => this.setState({data: response}));`  Though this is separate from the error described.  For the error described, can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David I have created a example page here:
 https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sky-hgv5cs?file=/src/api.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code [not included in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77023701/unable-to-run-function-shared-a-prop-to-dropdown?noredirect=1#comment135784039_77023701) you are importing a default export from `api`:

```
import demo from "./api";
```

(For the code *in the question* you call it `itemsName` instead of `demo`.)

However, `api` has no default export.  It only has named exports.  You'd import it like this:

```
import { demo } from "./api";
```

---

The next problem will be how you're using that function:

```
let response = this.props.api()
this.setState({data: response})
```

`api()` is an `async` function, so it returns a `Promise`.  That `Promise` won't be very useful to the `render` function (and has no `.map()` function).  If you want the *result* of that `Promise` then you'd either need to `await` it or follow it up with a `.then()` callback.  For example:

```
this.props.api().then(response => this.setState({data: response}));
```

Comment: Hey , 
I still face the issue of typeerror even after the fixes you recommended.

Comment: @AyudhSarkar: The same exact error from the same exact operation?  Can you update the sandbox example?

Comment: That is the problem. I fixed the code based on your recommendation and it works perfectly. But in my local system, I am facing "TypeError: this.props.api() is not a function".

Comment: @AyudhSarkar: Then the code in your local system is different from the code you're asking about.  Maybe the same error is happening in another instance of the component, maybe something else is broken, etc.  But if the example you've shown and asked about has been fixed then it's been fixed.  You might try creating a new runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem and asking a question about whatever *that* problem is.